# How to change image when two buttons are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make jQuery script where I will have 10 buttons all with different colors and after user clicks on two different buttons, combination of the clicked buttons colors will be made and switch the image frame with already prepared images based on color combinations.

My question is how to put conditions for two buttons(or links) clicked.

```
    <a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">switch me</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg" />

$(function() {
     $('.menulink').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
       $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
     });
    });
```

I want to achieve something like this but I want image to change when two buttons (or links) are clicked.
http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Sevdm/

Comment: quick and dirty: count 2 clicks then fire what you want... what is so hard about that?

Comment: use a variable to store information related to the button that was clicked, when another click happens check to see if there is any existing information on the variable, and use it with the information fr the current click, then clear it.

Comment: why not use on dblclick?

Comment: @JoeWarner because it is not going to be same button, I want event to happen when two different buttons are clicked one after another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation to track clicks on `.menulink` elements. using `e.delegateTarget` we can have the parent container hold a variable that determines if a `.menulink` element has been clicked previously, and if it has, we can have it change the background.

To do this I switched the `click` method to an `on` method. The `on` methods parameters are:

`$(element).on(event, delegated selector, function)`

[JQuery .on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Delegation simply means that instead of checking if each button has been clicked by placing an event on the button, we place an event on the container of the buttons and ask if the element that caused the event matches our delegated selector. If it does the provided function is fired. To access the parent of the delegated element within the code we can use the passed back event object, or in this case `e.delegateTarget`

[JQuery delegateTarget documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)

Since everything in JavaScript is an Object, we can assign new properties and methods to anything that is not explicitly part of the Browser's most base architecture. This absolutely includes the `body` of a page.

In the code below, I place a new property `clicked` on the `body` of the page. This is added on click of the first `.menulink` element, and is checked upon each subsequent click.

Because of this we can know if it is a second click by determining if `body.clicked` is true. If it is we tell the script to change the background image.

```js
$(function() {
     $('body').on("click", ".menulink", function(e){
     if(e.delegateTarget.clicked) $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
     else e.delegateTarget.clicked = true;
     e.preventDefault();
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">switch me</a>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">switch me</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg" />
```

Comment: Now I am not sure if I stated the problem in a right way so here is a basic code that will give you an idea of what I want.
`<script>
var hasBeenClicked = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit1").click(function(){
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    }); 
 var hasBeenClicked2 = false;
   $("#submit2").click(function(){
        hasBeenClicked2 = true;
    }); 
   if(hasBeenClicked==true && hasBeenClicked2==true){
    alert('The image has been changed');
   }
});
</script>`
When first button is clicked and second button is clicked, do something but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

provided you wanted to make sure the buttons were unique when clicked, you'll want a way of tracking which have been seen. I'm using a JS Object like a Set here for compat with older browsers.

```js
var clickCount = 0;//count the clicks
var clickTracker = {};//track which id's were clicked
var clickThreshold = 2;//the number of clicks we want before executing the if block
function clickHandler(){//callback function for the event
  if(clickTracker[this.id] === undefined){//we haven't seen this id yet
    clickCount++;//increment the number of buttons clicked
    clickTracker[this.id] = 1;//flag for tracking the click
    if(clickCount >= clickThreshold){//we saw at least clickThreshold clicks
      console.log(clickCount + 'unique clicks happened!');
      //your work here
    }
  }
}

$('.cls').click(clickHandler);//bind events
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn1' class='cls'>1</button>
<button id='btn2' class='cls'>2</button>
<button id='btn3' class='cls'>3</button>
<button id='btn4' class='cls'>4</button>
<button id='btn5' class='cls'>5</button>
```

Comment: Now I am not sure if I stated the problem in a right way so here is a basic code that will give you an idea of what I want.
`<script>
var hasBeenClicked = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit1").click(function(){
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    }); 
 var hasBeenClicked2 = false;
   $("#submit2").click(function(){
        hasBeenClicked2 = true;
    }); 
   if(hasBeenClicked==true && hasBeenClicked2==true){
    alert('The image has been changed');
   }
});
</script>`
When first button is clicked and second button is clicked, do something but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chosenColors = [];
  $(".colors button").click(function() {
    chosenColors.push($(this).text())
    check();
  });

  function check() {
    if (chosenColors.length === 2) {
      $(".pretty-picture").attr("src", chosenColors.sort().join("-") + ".png")
      chosenColors = [];
    }
  }
});

</script>

<body>
<div class=colors>
  <button type="button">red</button>
  <button type="button">yellow</button>
  <button type="button">blue</button>
</div>
<img class="pretty-picture">

</body>
```